What's the translation of a refeed in French?
A refeed is a:

periodic controlled intake of excess calories usually in the form of carbohydrates typically to improve weight loss during dieting

What's the translation of a refeed in French? Google Translate and Linguee didn't provide any interesting suggestions.

Dans le cadre du régime appliqué par les culturistes en vue d'une compétition, on parle de rebond glucidique.

Exemple: Guide complet du rebond glucidique pour la
musculation.

En Anglais, le terme "refeed" s'applique aussi dans les programmes alimentaires des bodybuilders.

Exemple: How To Maximize The Benefits Of Your Refeed Day.


Il n'y a pas de substantif équivalent, on pourrait appeler ça :
    épisode/cycle/phase (de régime) hyperglucidique contrôlé(e).
